Starting processes is very slow in git bash on Windows
I'm running git bash 2.45.2.1 on a windows computer (for work) and I've noticed that running even basic processes can be extremely slow.
For example,
$ time /usr/bin/echo 1 > /dev/null
real    0m0.102s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.015s

$ time /usr/bin/echo 1 | wc > /dev/null
real    0m0.151s
user    0m0.031s
sys     0m0.030s

Why would it take this version of bash a whole 0.1 s to spawn a process? Is this a Windows problem? Can this be fixed?
This can get very slow if I pipe even a hundred lines to xargs.
I don't think the slowness can be the hardware's fault. This computer's processor is a 13th Gen Intel Core i9-13950HX.
